# Anylogic model ceases execution at a specified time

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I don't know why the models stop working at this time of 127.33 days.
The model typically runs when I remove this code from the flowcharts, but when I added it, the model halted at the specified time.

Code:

```
while ( !collection.isEmpty() )
{
Order order = collection.getFirst();
if ( products > 0 )
{
if ( order.amount <= products )
{
order.retailer.products += order.amount;
traceln("order.amount fel backorder: " +order.amount + " for : " +order.retailer);
// remove the demand from the queue
collection.removeFirst();
}
}
}
```

[image: Problem Screenshot]

I've attempted to add code using an event that checks the inventory level is greater than 0 every day, but I've encountered the same issue.

Comment: are you sure that it stops always after 127.33 days? How many times this event occured?

Comment: Seems like a logic issue : if the order amount > `products` then you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, it's stack always at this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code:

```
LinkedList <Order> tempOrders=new LinkedList();
for(Order o : collection){
    tempOrders.add(o);
}

for(Order o : tempOrders){
    if(products>0){
             if(order.amounts<=products){
                  order.retailer.products+=order.amount;
                  collection.remove(o);
             }else{
            traceln("nothing happens because order.amounts is bigger than products... if i had used a while loop it would be stuck");
             }
      }else{
        traceln("another opportunity for my while loop to get stuck... nothing happens because products are equal to "+products);
      }
}

if(collection.size()>0){
    traceln("if i had used a while loop, it would be stuck right now");
}
```